Altair grouped bar chart with different categories per group
I am trying to make an altair grouped bar chart where each group has different categories.  The standard grouped bar chart plotting code produces plots where each plot's x-axis contains all categories, including those unused by a certain group.  The following code and produced plot illustrates the problem:
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Category': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 7, 8, 12, 18, 12, 10, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the grouped bar chart
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Category:N', title='Category'),
    y=alt.Y('Value:Q', title='Value'),
    column=alt.Column('Group:N', title='Group')
)

chart


Is there an easy way to remove categories that have no data for a specific group?  That is, the above chart should have 3 facets.  The first facet should contain only bars and x-axis for {A1, A2, A3}, the second and third should contain the B and C categories, respectively.   If there is no easy way to do this, I see two possible approaches:

Manually delete categories from each facet that do not contain data in a group.  How do I do this?

Create individual bar charts and then concatenate them horizontally.  I would want the plots to share the same scale (and other properties like colors that I will add later) and also have "Group" labels for each of the subplots.  Is there an easy way to do this that does not require a lot of boilerplate (like manually computing range of data, adding group titles to each subplot, etc.)?



Altair has the ability to resolve each axes' scale independently:

import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Category': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 7, 8, 12, 18, 12, 10, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the grouped bar chart
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Category:N', title='Category'),
    y=alt.Y('Value:Q', title='Value'),
    column=alt.Column('Group:N', title='Group')
)

chart.resolve_scale(x='independent')


Thank you. Is there a way to control the label alignment for a horizontal bar chart?  When one of the sub-plots has a long label name, the "category" label is misaligned across subplots.

Yes, you can call .axis(minExtent=XXX) on the X object to ensure all the axis titles are at least XXX pixels from the labels. I don't believe there is a way to have XXX determined automatically.
